# with facebook plugin, I can't build

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

I have Ionic application, and when I install the ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook-connect --variable APP_ID = "123456789" --variable APP_NAME = "myApplication", I can't build. If I uninstall the plugin, I make the perfect build.

I add error message requesting help please.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list:
  Error while merging dex archives:
  Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
  Program type already present: android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$CallbackHandler

Ionic:
   Ionic CLI                     : 6.10.0 (C:\Users\Estelita\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.6.4
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1102.9
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 11.2.9
   @angular/cli                  : 11.2.9
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 3.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I am the maintainer of `cordova-plugin-facebook-connect`. I'm guessing you are getting this error because you are using some plugin that still relies on the old Android Support Library. Can you confirm, do you have AndroidX enabled? Are you using `cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter`?

Comment: (Sorry for my bad english...) Thank you very much for answering, I removed the platform, installed the two plugins you name, then the facebook-connect, I included the platform and it's perfect! thanks !